# Short and open circuit in radio frequency

Tags: rf, circuit-design

I have been recently reading a bit on RF design, in particular stub matching.

However one point that I failed to grasp is how open and short circuits at high frequencies work. In particular why does the below stub not produce a short circuit:

[image]

What is the physics behind this that allows this circuit to function?

Another related question is, "creating an RF short circuit that is DC-open" which mentions a RF short can be created with a quarter wavelength open-stub. I understand that with a open-stub of appropriate length a RF short circuit can be produced. However the question is:

1. Does this RF short circuit have the same meaning as our normal short-ciruit i.e. very high current flowing?
2. What is the physics or reasoning that I can produce a short circuit with a DC-open?

Comment: Do you understand transmission line theory a little bit? How about reflections and load mismatch? These are basics needed to be understood before you might grasp the physics.

Comment: Also try looking up resonance in pipes with open and closed ends. It's very related.

Comment: btw short circuit does not necessarilly mean high current. It means a part of the circuit is shorted by a low impedant connection.

Answer (score 4):

You should study why open-ended and closed-ended pipes resonate: -

[image]

Picture from [here](http://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Sound/text/Sound_waves_in_tubes/index.html)

It's the same mechanism as an electrical stub (open or short).

So, in the top example the closed-end pipe will resonate when the applied frequency is such that the length (L) is a quarter wavelength of the frequency. When the pipe is resonant it acts like a parallel resonant tuned circuit and offers a high impedance to the applied frequency. This is the shorted quarter wave stub.

In the lower example, the pipe is open-ended and, to produce a parallel resonance (high impedance) requires a pipe length (L) twice as long.

This is an open half wave stub and is resonant exactly the same as a shorted quarter wave stub but requires twice the length.

If a quarter wave stub is open circuit it behaves like a series resonant tuned circuit and this produces an impedance of zero ohms at resonance. Horses for courses.

> *1) Does this RF short circuit have the same meaning as our normal
>   short-ciruit i.e. very high current flowing?*

Yes it has the same meaning but only at the precise frequency where it becomes a short.

> *2) What is the physics or reasoning that I can produce a short circuit
>   with a DC-open?*

Well, the pipe analogy above should help you understand that. Here's more of an electrical picture: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.rfcafe.com/references/qst/review-transmission-lines-circuit-elements-november-1966-qst.htm).

Comment: sorry from your answer do you mean that open-ended and closed-ended pipes acts similar to an shorted stub? from a pure imaginative point of view, an close-ended pipe would act more like a open stub? Or am I talking out of my rear

Comment: A closed ended quarter wave pipe acts like a closed-ended quarter wave electrical stub i.e. parallel (high impedance) resonance.